# Execute files from /bin/dir

Tags: ubuntu

How do you make the directories under your local bin executable too?

Eg

I'm able to execute 
    ~/bin/a.out 
but not 
    ~/bin/dir/a.out

Comment: What error message do you get? In general, it doesn't matter where your binaries are, as long as they are `chmod +x` for you.

Comment: You can use a recursive chmod +x on your local dir with -R

Comment: This nice introduction might help: [File security](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html)

Comment: @tripleee I get the error message "a.out: Command not found" and the directory is executable for me. However I believe that I need to edit ~/.profile somehow but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add the directory to your PATH environmental variable. I don't think its possible with the common shells (ba)sh to have the path search be recursive, so you would need to set it manually.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/dir
```

To automate this and support multiple sub-directories, add this to your .profile:

```
PATH=${PATH}:$(find ~/bin -type d | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')
```

Just to clarify, the variable PATH is a list of directories to search for executables when an unknown command is entered. The delimiter is : as you can see with the command:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Or use a full path, `~/bin/dir/a.out` rather than just `a.out`; but as this is what the OP wrote in the question, I assumed s/he was already doing that.